after git reset last year's github contribution counter outdated
After doing git reset on a remote repo and push --force my GitHub contribution counter from the last year was not updated from 16 to 15, however within the project the number is correct showing 15 commit.
How can I get the correct number to be shown?

It's not a git issue. Contact Github support and ask them to rebuild your contribution stats.
